# Can I play Steam's MK: Komplete Edition on two PC's?

Tags: steam, mortal-kombat-9, mortal-kombat-komplete-edition

Do I have to pay twice for play with my friend and is there multiplayer on mk: kp?

Comment: You can share the game with your friend, but then you can't play at the same time unless one of you goes offline. If one of you is offline, you can't play together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to pay twice, because you need to buy the game on your friend's account.

Also, there is a multiplayer function in MK:KE.